# ActiveLdap - Move user from one container to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ldap

I have a user with the following:

```
'cn=example_user, ou=Person, dc=example, dc=com'
```

Using ActiveLdap, I'd like to change the container to:

```
'cn=example_user, ou=Inactive, dc=example, dc=com'
```

I'm missing something... I've searched and looked at the source code, and the possibility seems to be there but I'm not seeing how it's done.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out.  Here's what I did:

1. After running `setup_connection`

   ```
   ActiveLdap::Base.setup_connection(host: host, port: port, etc.)
   ```
2. Call the `modify_rdn` method on `connection`

   ```
   ActiveLdap::Base.connection.modify_rdn(dn, new_rdn, remove_old_rdn, new_superior, options={})
   ```

I created a `change_ou(new_ou)` instance method on the model with `ldap_mapping`, so I pass:

- `dn` for `dn`
- `"cn=#{cn}"` for `new_rdn`
- `true` for `remove_old_rdn`
- `"ou=#{new_ou},dc=example,dc=com"` for `new_superior`

The variable `new_ou` is, of course, the name of the new container(which would be "Inactive" in my example above). I don't pass anything for options since it defaults to any empty hash.

Below is the link to the source code for the `modify_rdn` method.  I was having a hard time figuring out that it needed to be called from `ActiveLdap::Base.connection`:

https://github.com/activeldap/activeldap/blob/master/lib/active_ldap/adapter/base.rb#L236

Answer (score 1):

Use the MODIFY DN operation for this purpose. See also:

- [LDAP: Moving and Renaming Entries](http://ldapmaven.com/2011/08/01/mastering-moddn/)

Comment: I was looking for how to do it with the ActiveLdap gem specifically.  Thanks for your answer though. It did get the gears going again as I knew I must be on the right path.